# All instances Pipe Are busy - c# NamedPipeServerStream

Tags: c#, io, stream, pipe, namedpipeserverstream

im trying to use pipe via .net v4.0 on winforms application background

heres my code -->

```
public void main()
{
    using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeserver = new NamedPipeServerStream("colors", PipeDirection.Out,4))
    {

        pipeserver.WaitForConnection();
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeserver))
            {
                string data = sr.ReadLine();
                ConvertToGuiColor(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

trying to understand why Exception "All instances Pipe Are busy"
thought maybe because

```
pipeserver.WaitForConnection();
```

,but the Exception is throwing in this :
 "using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeserver = new NamedPipeServerStream("colors", PipeDirection.Out,4))"
 command

ty for helpers 
sKY Walker

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570652/all-instances-busy-exception-on-named-pipe-creation helpful?